# multiple pointers on device memory for single allocated array in cuda

Tags: cuda, thrust

I am wondering if there is it possible to setup multiple pointers to single data already allocated in memory? the reason i am asking this is because i was implementing lexographical sorting with gpu with the help of thrust vectors (and failed miserably in terms of time)

for example i am trying to acheive equivalent of these c++ statments

```
unsigned int * pword;      //setting up the array of memory for permutations of word
pword = new unsigned int [N*N];

unsigned int* * p_pword;    //pointers to permutation words
p_pword = new unsigned int* [N];

//setting up the pointers on the locations such that if N=4 then 0,4,8,12,...
int count;
for(count=0;count<N;count++)
        p_pword[count]=&pword[count*N];
```

I am not asking for someone to provide me with code, i just want to know is there any way i can setup pointers to single array of data.
PS: i have tried the following method but not achieving any speedup at all

```
int * raw_ptr = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&d_Data[0]); //doing same with multiple pointers
```

but i guess due to the fact that i am pointing towards device_vector it might be the problem of slow accessing

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well this doesn't make any sense:

```
int * raw_ptr = thrust::raw_pointer_cast([0]);
                                          ^ what is this??
```

I don't think that line would compile correctly.

But in thrust you can certainly do something like this:

```
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>

int main(){

  int N=16;
  thrust::device_vector<int> d_A(4*N);
  thrust::sequence(d_A.begin(), d_A.end());
  thrust::device_ptr<int> p_A[N];
  for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    p_A[i] = &(d_A[4*i]);
  thrust::host_vector<int> h_A(N);
  thrust::copy(p_A[4], p_A[8], h_A.begin());
  for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    printf("h_A[%d] = %d\n", i, h_A[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

Not sure what to say about speedup.  Speedup in the context of the tiny little snippet of code you've posted doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Thanks again Robert Crovella for reply actually i was trying to do this
    int * raw_ptr = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&d_Data[0]);

Comment: Nice answer by the way (but i already did that using thrust's device_ptrs), and sorry if i was confusing in asking question
i wanted to ask that is there any way i can make array of pointers save the address of single array in CUDA memory (let's say unsigned int *d_Data)

i have implemented the same logic you described above in my example but i was looking for multiple pointers to single array (not device_vector)

Comment: That should work.  But its creating a pointer that is not conveniently usable in thrust algorithms.  You would be able to use that pointer in ordinary CUDA code, however.